Is there an option to view executed C compiler commands in cgo?
While cross-compiling a Go project for ARM on FreeBSD I came across a few errors that don't make sense, for example unsupported option -mno-thumb or unused option -marm. I suspect that there is potentially a bug in the tool that compiles C code.
Therefore I'd like to see the exact command(s) invoked by cgo when it compiles/links C code so that I can reproduce the error.
I know that there is the -x flag in go build. Unfortunately, it doesn't show the full set of options being passed to the C compiler (or at least I don't see the flags mentioned in error messages in there).
Is there another way?
Found a GitHub issue with a similar question but it has been closed with no answer: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/45724
Update:
I wrote a wrapper script that prints the whole clang command which I can feed to go via CC, but it doesn't show any sign of -mno-thumb, and CFLAGS is empty as well. I have no idea where this argument comes from.
#!/bin/sh
echo "clang args: $@" >&2
echo "CPPFLAGS: $CPPFLAGS" >&2
echo "CFLAGS: $CFLAGS" >&2
echo "CXXFLAGS: $CXXFLAGS" >&2
clang -v "$@

clang -v doesn't want to print the full command either - it fails before even getting to that (which is kind of dumb IMO).
FreeBSD clang version 17.0.6 (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git llvmorg-17.0.6-0-g6009708b4367)
Target: x86_64-unknown-freebsd13.3
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
clang: error: unsupported option '-mno-thumb' for target 'x86_64-unknown-freebsd13.3'

Note: I'm not sure why it says x86_64 - it should be arm (I guess that's why compilation fails - wrong target arch).
